# External image using img src not allowing integer parameter

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I am trying to get an image from an external source in Play Framework. When working with just the string this works fine, but I need to pass to the controller an Integer also but this always give me a not applicable to String error. I think this is because of the img src html tag I am using. item.Myjob is the string and works fine by itself, item.MyItem is the integer

```
 <img src ="@routes.ImagesController.getImage(item.MyJob,Item.MyItem)"/>
```

My plan is to pass the parameters to the image controller from the parameters I have to make up the path and the image file name and then return the image. Or any other advice on how this can be achieved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do this?

Why not pass a list of items with their image ids, and a for loop; if you want to get the list of items and their images? Something like:

```
//In controller
case class Item (name: String, picId: Int, whateverElse: Any) 

//In your views
@(items: List[Item])

@for(item <- items){
  @item.name
  <img src="whateverPath/@item.picId">   
}
```

or...

In a case you have a small application and unique items, you could simply make the image ids the same as items' names; so you don't need to look for it.

Comment: I have solved the issue I was having but now one of the parameters I want to pass is a date. I have a pathbinder setup but on using this route it comes up with badrequest Invalid Date format.

I have the date formatted it both the pathbinder and the model as 

    (pattern="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.zzz")

Any ideas on what else can be causing this invalid date format?